# Cannot access correct value in React useState at first render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is a bit of a weird and deep problem, I will try to explain at my best.

I'm using React state to keep my user state update through my Chrome/Firefox extension app.
I grab some values from my cookies (with a custom Hook), save them in the user state and then pass them to my components.
Something that is driving me crazy happens in my components: If I access to the whole user state, I can see the correct user's values. If I access to a specific property from the user state object, I get another value!!

Here is the code:
useState sync with cookies custom hook:

```
import { useState, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react'
import { UserContextProps, UserStateProps, USER_STATE_DEFAULT } from '../context/UserContext'
import {
  COOKIE_NAME_LANGUAGE,
  COOKIE_NAME_ADULT_FILTER,
  COOKIE_NAME_NEW_TAB,
  COOKIE_NAME_SEARCH_COUNT,
  getCookieValue,
  setCookie,
} from '../helpers/_cookies'

const cookiesName: { [key: string]: any } = {
  numOfSearches: COOKIE_NAME_SEARCH_COUNT,
  language: COOKIE_NAME_LANGUAGE,
  adultContentFilter: COOKIE_NAME_ADULT_FILTER,
  openInNewTab: COOKIE_NAME_NEW_TAB,
}

const mergeCookiesWithUserState = (defaultUserState: UserStateProps): UserStateProps => {
  const newUserState = { ...defaultUserState }

  for (const key in newUserState) {
    if (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(cookiesName, key)) {
      const printAddress = async () => {
        const cookieValue = await getCookieValue(cookiesName[key])

        if (cookieValue !== undefined) {
          newUserState[key] = cookieValue
        }
      }

      printAddress()
    }
  }

  return newUserState
}

export const useUserStateSyncedWithCookies = (): UserContextProps => {
  const initialUserState = useMemo(() => mergeCookiesWithUserState(USER_STATE_DEFAULT), [])

  const [userState, _setUserState] = useState(initialUserState)

  const setUserState = useCallback((nextState: Partial<UserStateProps>): void => {
    _setUserState((prevState) => {
      const newState = {
        ...prevState,
        ...nextState,
      }
      newState.adultContentFilter = Number(newState.adultContentFilter)
      newState.language = Number(newState.language)

      for (const key in nextState) {
        if (Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(cookiesName, key)) {
          setCookie(cookiesName[key], newState[key], { expires: 365 })
        }
      }

      return newState
    })
  }, [])
  console.log({ userState }) // Here i console log my user state and I get all teh updated value from my cookies.

  return {
    userState,
    setUserState,
  }
}
```

Just for complete information here is the `getCookies() function`

```
export async function getCookieValue(name: CookieName) {
    const promiseCookie = new Promise<string | number | boolean | undefined>((resolve, reject) => {
      extensionApiObject.cookies.getAll({}, (cookies) => {
        const filteredCookies = cookies.filter((cookie) => {
          return cookie.domain === 'elliotforwater.com' && cookie.name === name
        })

        resolve(convertCookieValue(name, filteredCookies[0]?.value))
      })
    })

    return promiseCookie.then()
}
```

And in my App.tsx for example I have:

```
function App() {
  const user = useUserStateSyncedWithCookies()

console.log(user) // user = { numbOfSearch: 1}
console.log(user.numOfSearches) // 0  !!! WHY?!

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={user}>
      <Background>
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Dashboard />
        </div>

        <Modal.Host />
      </Background>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  )
}
export default App
```

You can find the whole code on github here:
https://github.com/ElliotForWater/elliot-dashboard/blob/develop

https://github.com/ElliotForWater/elliot-dashboard/blob/develop/src/App.tsx

https://github.com/ElliotForWater/elliot-dashboard/blob/develop/src/hooks/useUserStateSyncedWithCookies.tsx

Answer (score 0):

Since getCookieValue returns a promise so at the time of consoling user it will not have any value but after a while, it returns the value of the user asynchronously which gets updated in the console log. This does not happen in the case of object properties.

This is a well-known peculiarity (an optimization) of most browser consoles : the tree is only built when you open the object, with the new values of the object.

If you want to see the state of the object at the time of logging, supposing it's a small enough and not self referencing object, you may clone it like this :

`console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(user));`

To resolve this just use await for the promise and then you should get expected results.

Comment: hey thanks @Mohd Samoon! I thought that has to be with async but i didn't know about the browser console peculiarity. 
I do already await for the promise.. You can see it in the first block of code, the hook. Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: Can you try in getCookieValue function
`
const result = await promiseCookie;
return result
`
And try to console the result object also to see what you get.